# joomla 3.3, featured articles and tags

Tags: joomla, tags

I'm using the most current version of joomla 3. I just started using the tags feature and adding a few relevant tags to each article which so far seems to be a nice feature.

The problem I am running into is: the featured articles on the homepage are showing the tags. I want to exclude them from showing on the homepage featured articles but I need them to show in the full text article.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question. Ask on [joomla.se]

Comment: Oh sorry. Didn't know. Did ask on Joomla but no one is responding. Thanks.

Comment: There should be a menu option to turn them off.

Comment: @user3727526 I was going to take a look but I can't find your question on [joomla.se]

Comment: Elin - depending on the menu type, you can do that but not for featured articles.

Comment: @Mike - here is the link (I hope) http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=848015, looks like I just got one response.

Comment: @Mike I solved the issue. I ended up copying the featured article files from t3 system plugin into my templates html/com content folder. That only took a couple of days. Thanks.

Comment: @user3727526 Ah - I meant that you should post your question on http://joomla.stackexchange.com. Glad you have a solution.